# Can someone help on this Markov Chain question?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix

Consider a general chain with state space $S = \left\{1, 2\right\}$ and write the
transition matrix as
$$
P = \begin{pmatrix} 1-a & a \\ b & 1-b \end{pmatrix}
$$
Use the Markov property to show that
$$
\operatorname{Pr}\left\{X_{n+1} = 1\right\} − \frac{b}{a+b} 
    = (1 − a − b)\left[\operatorname{Pr}\left\{X_n = 1\right\} − \frac{b}{a+b}\right]
$$
I'm using the fact that $p(1,1)=1-a$ and trying to equate this to $\operatorname{Pr}\left\{X_{n+1}=1\mid X_n=1\right\}$ to try and get $\operatorname{Pr}\left\{X_{n+1}=1\right\}$ and $\operatorname{Pr}\left\{X_n=1\right\}$ individually but I cant work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you would want to use the fact that
$$
\operatorname{Pr}\left\{X_{n+1}=1\right\} = \operatorname{Pr}\left\{X_{n+1}=1 \mid X_n=1\right\}\operatorname{Pr}\left\{X_n=1\right\}+\operatorname{Pr}\left\{X_{n+1} = 1 \mid X_n = 2\right\}(1-\operatorname{Pr}\left\{X_n=1)\right\}
$$
and fill in the conditional probabilities from the transition matrix.